# Android SharedPreferences empty after commit

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Why is in the following example the foo false?

```
mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
mPrefs.edit().putBoolean("myValue",true);
mPrefs.edit().commit();

boolean foo = mPrefs.getBoolean("myValue",false);
```

Comment: Just separate `mPrefs.edit().putBoolean("myValue",true);`  to `Editor editor = mPrefs.edit(); editor.putBoolean("myValue",true);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to write in this way

```
mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
mPrefs.edit().putBoolean("myValue",true).commit();

boolean foo = mPrefs.getBoolean("myValue",false);
```

Comment: care to explain why it should be written in *that way* ?

Answer (score 1):

When you call `edit()` the first time, you are not saving the `boolean` and so it does not exist when you retrieve it.

```
mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
mPrefs.edit().putBoolean("myValue",true).commit();
boolean foo = mPrefs.getBoolean("myValue",false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Store your values by--->

```
SharedPreferences prefs =PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean("myValue",true);
editor.apply();
```

to get your result--->

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Boolean b = sharedPreferences.getboolean("myValue","");
```

Answer (score -1):

You should `Edit` the `SharedPreference` object through `Editor`

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt("Key", value);
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score -1):

Save value in shared preferences:

```
SharedPreferences settings =getSharedPreferences("AppName", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString(key, value);
    editor. putBoolean(key, value);
            editor.commit();
```

get value from shared preferences:

```
  SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("AppName", 0);
            String value=settings.getString(key, ""); 
    boolean value=settings.getBoolean(key,false);
```